# Django HttpResponse with redirect

Tags: python, django, httpresponse

I have a function that download a excel file in django:

```
 x= Y.objects.filter(pk__in=ids)
 response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
 response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=Test.xlsx'
 test_data= WriteFile(x)
 response.write(test_data)
 return response
```

My objective it's to appear a message after this:

```
messages.success(request, 'Success!')
```

But I need to redirect after the `return response` because if not the message not appear and only appear if I refresh the page manually.

Any ideas how to make the message appear after download a file with the `return response`?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't necessarily need to *redirect* to show the message, though you could.

If instead of writing `test_data` to the response directly, you were to render a [template response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/template-response/#templateresponse-objects) which included that data, then you could also include the success message in that template response.

If you do want to redirect, then you would need to:

1. Store `test_data` in something persistent—e.g. a file on disk, or a database record
2. Expose an endpoint to fetch this data from your persistent store and render it (along with any Django messages)
3. Redirect to that endpoint using [HttpResponseRedirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect)

Comment: Yes I can't do with this method... Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, I didn't read the question carefully enough. Missed the whole "Content-Disposition" part. In that case what I'd suggest is similar to what @brunodesthuilliers advises in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can only return one single response for a request, you cannot both redirect and return an attachment in the same response (well it *might* be technically legal - you'll have to carefully re-read the whole HTTP spec to find out -, but the client will most certainly ignore the response body when he gets a redirect status code, at least I newer saw a browser acting otherwise so far), and an "attachment" response will indeed not trigger a reload of the page you came for (the server cannot do this and a browser will not).

IOW, if you *really* want to have both a page refresh AND a download, you will need at least two views and some javascript - the first view creates the attachment and stores it somewhere, then return a html response with the "success" message, a link to the second view (with a reference to the attachment) and a js snippet that will trigger a click on this link, the second view only serves the attachment.